# Read DOCX file to get word count with Java?

Tags: java, word-count

Is there a library that can do this? I've looked at docx4j but it didn't(I think) have a functionality to count words of the docx file.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: You could write one yourself?

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc if i knew how, i would.

Comment: read the file into a string and then do `string.split(" ").length`

Comment: @j.con is suggesting probably the easiest way of doing it.  You could then look for anything that doesn't seem to be a word and drop it from the array

Answer (score 1):

The best java Library is [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/document/index.html)

```
import java.io.File;  
import java.io.FileInputStream;  
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;  
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.sql.Connection;  
import java.sql.DriverManager;  
import java.sql.SQLException;  
import java.sql.Statement;  

import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;  
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor;  


public class NewDocReader {  

public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException  
{  


File docFile=new File("c:\\multi\\multi.docx");   // file object was created  
FileInputStream finStream=new FileInputStream(docFile.getAbsolutePath()); // file input stream with docFile  
HWPFDocument doc=new HWPFDocument(finStream);// throws IOException and need to import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;  
WordExtractor wordExtract=new WordExtractor(doc); // import  org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor  
String [] dataArray =wordExtract.getParagraphText();  
// dataArray stores the each line from the document  

int pozicijaBlankoMesta;  
for(int i=0;i<dataArray.length;i++)  
{  .............
}
```

}